Get all latest documents in a collection
In Mongo DB I have a number of documents.
They each have a insertion_date column which is Date type.
Will store data in following format:
2024-04-03T07:00:00:00.000Z

I want to fetch all the latest documents based on latest date.
Lets say the collection has 20 documents.
The insertion_date for 10 of them is: 2024-04-03T07:00:00:00.000Z
And remaining 10 is: 2019-01-02T01:00:00:00.000Z
The latest date between these is 2024-04-03T07:00:00:00.000Z.
So fetch all 10 records that has this latest insertion_date.
There can be multiple dates. So find latest date and all records that fall under this date.
I will not know before hand the number of records. It is 10 in this example only.
I am trying to write a query for this in NodeJS using Mongoose.
I could query it as follows but it ends up returning all 20 records.
I can't limit it cos I do not know there are 10 records.
Could I get some help with this pls.
router.get('/products/:locale', async (req, res) => {
  const locale = req?.params?.locale;
  try {
    const products = await Product.find({ locale })
      .sort({ insertion_date: -1 })
      // .limit(10);
    res.json(products);
  } catch (error) {
    // error handling
  }
});


My proposal would be $setWindowFields.
Could be this:
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $setWindowFields: {
         output: {
            lastest_date: { $max: "$insertion_date" }
         }
      }
   },
   { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$insertion_date", "$lastest_date"] } } }
])

or this one:
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $setWindowFields: {
         sortBy: { insertion_date: -1 },
         output: {
            rank: { $denseRank: {} }
         }
      }
   },
   { $match: { rank: 1 } }
])

Mongo Playground

This can be done with one query using Model.aggregate:
const products = await Product.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "locale": locale
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "insertion_date": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $facet: {
      docs: []
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      docs: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$docs",
          as: "doc",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$doc.insertion_date",
              {
                $arrayElemAt: [
                  "$docs.insertion_date",
                  0
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$docs"
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: "$docs"
  }
])

See HERE for a working example with some simple illustrative documents added.
Explanation:

$match your locale to your req.params.locale value.
$sort - by insertion_date: -1.
$facet - using this stage after the $sort is efficient if the $sort made use of an index on insertion_date and I would advise you add one if you haven't already. It therefore won't do a COLLSCAN and will transform your collection into a single array named docs.
$project the docs array but...
$filter the docs array to only return documents where the insertion_date is $eq to the insertion_date of the first element from docs array.
$unwind the docs array .
$replaceWith - will set the root of the results to the unwound docs.

Edit: added a $match stage as I just noticed you were querying on a locale field. Documents updated on the linked example as well.
